# Regex LookAround working in python but don't work in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I have a fairly good understanding about the Regex work in Python but the same regex string for lookaround work don't work in C++. I have tested this with following [example](https://regex101.com/r/5ad2Cu/1)  This looks fine. However, same string shows false for the following C++ code fragment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
const char* rejectReason = "Failed to execute SQL. Error=ORA-00936: missing expression";    
regex rgx(".+?(?=(ORA-([0-9]{5}):))");
cout<<regex_match(rejectReason, rgx)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am somewhat new to C++ and many references shows that lookahead works but look after don't work in C++  and no mention about this lookaround. So isn't there any straight forward way to do this in C++?

Comment: You do know theres capture groups with this right? You would want the first group...

Comment: Do you mean many matches? Yes, At least one and there can be more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as starter, this will give you a basic idea how `regex` library works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string rejectReason = "Failed to execute SQL. Error=ORA-00936: missing expression";
    regex rgx(".*Error=ORA-([0-9]{5}).*$");
    if (regex_match(rejectReason, rgx)) {
        cout << "String matches" <<endl;
    }

    smatch match;
    string result;
    if (regex_search(rejectReason, match, rgx) && match.size() > 1) {
        result = match.str(1);
    } else {
        result = string("");
    }

    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After  going through your code, I  understood that I dont have to complicate things.